# after changing my json format i got this error "Value should be a JSON object"

Tags: json, validation, zabbix

I have this data as JSON and I pass it to Zabbix for a disk IO discovery:

```
{
"data":[
{ "{#DEVICE_NAME}":"/dev/sde1" },
{ "{#DEVICE_NAME}":"/dev/sdf1" }
]
}
```

and it is working perfectly.

Then I needed more values so I added another field and created another template for testing it:

```
{
"data":[
{ "{#OS_FS}":"/dev/sdb1", "{#DEFINED_FS}":"/data1" },
{ "{#OS_FS}":"/dev/sdd1", "{#DEFINED_FS}":"/data3" },
{ "{#OS_FS}":"/dev/sdc1", "{#DEFINED_FS}":"/data2" }
]
}
```

But I got this error when I added a host to template: "Value should be a JSON object". I tested its validation with some online JSON validator and it's correct. What should I do?

Comment: It's likely you are not sending that exact JSON. Doublecheck what you are sending - is it the exact same data, is it the correct Zabbix server, is it the correct host, correct item and so on. Also, how does the LLD rule get this data?

Comment: @Richlv  with a key. and its key is defined in configuration. i'll check again.

Answer (score -2):

Below format should work :

```
    {
"data":[
[{ "{#OS_FS}":"/dev/sdb1", "{#DEFINED_FS}":"/data1" }],
[{ "{#OS_FS}":"/dev/sdd1", "{#DEFINED_FS}":"/data3" }],
[{ "{#OS_FS}":"/dev/sdc1", "{#DEFINED_FS}":"/data2" }]
]
}
```

Comment: Hi, Manish - unfortunately that does not follow the Zabbix LLD JSON syntax (see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#creating_custom_lld_rules) - and it is always great to explain answers.